# iPhone MessageUI email attachments not being sent to receiver

Tags: iphone, email, pdf, png, attachment

I am trying to attach an image and a pdf to an email using the MessageUI framework. I followed the [MailComposer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MailComposer/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008865) example in the Apple documentation.

On the iPhone it seems to work perfectly, the image and the pdf both show up in the body of the send mail window as expected.

However, when I receive the email on my MacBook there are two problems.

1) myImage.png shows up as an attachment and is the correct dimensions but is totally blank

2) myPDF.pdf doesn't show up as an attachment at all

But, when I receive the mail on my iPhone, myImage.png shows up fine. myPDF.pdf still doesn't show up in mail on my iPhone though.

Hope someone can shed some light on what might be happening.

Here is the relevant code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@"Test Email"];

 // Attach an image to the email
 NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myImage" ofType:@"png"];
 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
 [picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"myImage"];


// Attach a PDF file to the email
NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPDF" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];
[picker addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"myPDF"];


// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = @"This is a test.";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

**EDIT** Instead of saving and retrieving my image and PDF to my mainBundle I used NSDocumentsDirectory and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem regarding the image attachment. Using this, I was able to send and actually receive the attached image:

```
//attachment
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

[picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"theImage"];
```

I didn't try pdf sending, sorry.

Just my two cents,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it actually would cause your problem, but most people seem to include filename extensions on the fileName parameter to addAttachmentData, i.e.

```
[picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"myImage.png"];
```

Comment: Actually that is not necessary as the file type has already been specified in pathForResource:ofType: However, I did try it anyway and it made no difference.

Comment: pathForResourceOfType is about *loading* the data, whereas the fileName parameter might have affected how email clients were *interpreting* the data....  can you post a dump of the email as you're receiving it on the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and I determined that the `MFMailComposeViewController` is packaging the `MIME` for the `PDF` file with **7-bit transfer** encoding, rather than quoted-printable or **base-64** encoding. Obviously you cannot email binary files using 7-bit encoding. So either there is a transfer-encoding setting on a `MFMailComposeViewController` that I am missing or this object has a serious shortcoming.

Answer (score 0):

Try This ,This one worked for me .

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@"Test Email"];

 // Attach an image to the email
 NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myImage" ofType:@"png"];
 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
 [picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"myImage"];


// Attach a PDF file to the email
//NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPDF" ofType:@"pdf"];
//NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];

[picker addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"myPDF.pdf"];


// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = @"This is a test.";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

   // [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    [picker release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this as I was having the same issue...little old but in case anyone comes across this here is what helped me....

I was able to add my attachments in as usual (using 6 attachments of various types)...they would show up in the email body...but the receiver would never get all of the attachments....only one.

I pulled the files into my editor (drag and drop into your m or h files) and it showed the file path.  Turns out that I had neglected to copy the first file to my project so the app was pulling from my local drive and then stopping as the other files I was trying to attach were not in the same folder.  Once I pulled all of the attachments from the same location they all pulled in fine.

Hope that helps someone.